# Setting correct proj4 string/info using GDAL

Tags: gdal, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am going to try and be as clear as I can - because I don't exactly know what I am doing but I am trying my best. I am sure this is probably simple but I have tried for hours to figure this out. *I am trying to convert my .tif file to a raster tileset using GDAL tools.*

For reference, I am using the following .TIF :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/85zgh1ragye27nd/tif.zip?dl=0

It is 1+MB zipped on Dropbox and 60+MB unzipped. This is "super resolution" NEXRAD weather data from a Texas radar during a tornado. It has been warped to ESPG:3857 for use in Mapbox previously (and that is what I need it in). Below is a screenshot after running gdalinfo.

[image]

---

With that out of the way... I am at the point where I am using gdal2tiles to convert the .tif to a tileset. But, I am getting the following error :

```
ERROR 6 : No translation for an empty SRS to PROJ.4 format is known
```

After doing research on this error, it looks like I need to define the proj4 string. (This is where I no experience at all.)

I found [This link](https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/scicomp/recipes/gdal-reproject) which gives instructions on adding the string to the raster file. But, is this what I need to be doing anyway?

I found https://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7483/ to have proj4 information, but I am not sure how to add it to my .TIF - or if that would even fix it. Below is what apparently is missing from my .TIF.

```
+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs
```

I would add examples of what I have tried but I have done too many variations and I don't want to make a mess out of this question.

It looks like there is no coordinate system defined from gdalinfo, so is this what I should be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened the original TIFF file with QGIS and defined the coordinate system as EPSG:4326. The centre of the round area is at around -98.0260,29.6440. It seems that the offset is not introduced by gdal2tiles but it exists already in KEWX_L2_REF_COLORIZED.tif. Perhaps the original coordinate system is not EPSG:4326 but some other that is close to it. Unfortunately it is hard to guess what the real CRS could be, or if there is a need to apply grid shifts.

[image]